# numpy dot or einsum for multiplying N 2x2 arrays with a 2xn array

Tags: numpy

I want to multiply (matrix multiplication) N 2x2 arrays with a 2xN array.

```py
n = np.array([1,2,3])
m = np.array([[n,0*n],[0*n,0*n+1]]).T
# shape: (3, 2, 2)
# [[[1 0]
#   [0 1]]

#  [[2 0]
#   [0 1]]

#  [[3 0]
#   [0 1]]]

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
# shape: (2, 3)
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]]
```

So the result should be

```
[[1 4 9]
 [4 5 6]]
```

This should be possible with einsum or dot, but I failed with both. From what I read, a solution with dot would potentially be faster.

**edit**: To give some more context: This is really just a (2x2) matrix multiplication on a 2xn vector. But there are n different matrices: One for each of the n vector elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.einsum` as follow:

```
import numpy as np

n = np.array([1,2,3])
m = np.array([[n,0*n],[0*n,0*n+1]]).T

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

result = np.einsum('nij, jn->in', m, x)
```

In the `einsum`, `n` is the index that lie in the three dimensions, `i` and `j` are the indexes for the sums between 2x2 matrices and 2-dimensional arrays.

`result` is:

```
array([[1, 4, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: This is 'kind of' correct. The correct result is buried inside of that at least. But you still need to get it out. And more of a concern: This does way more multiplications than necessary. edit: The expected output is in the question

Comment: Can you write your expected output?

Comment: It's directly under "So the result should be"

Comment: if you just want the expected output try... np.einsum('ijk,...ji->ji',m,x)